# Convert yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have a scenario where my input date format is `yyyy-MM-dd` and required output date format must be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` in Java 8 or above.
Example:

Input: `2022-03-15`
Expected O/P : `2022-03-15 12:00:00.000`

Comment: Where would the "12 minutes past 12" part of the output come from? Have you tried anything yet? (There are *hundreds* of questions about converting between date/time formats already...)

Comment: Use string concatenation to add " 12:00:12.000" to your input string. It doesn't really make sense to add a time to your date if you don't have a meaningful time.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I did tried that. but that wasn't a good solution. Temporarily it may work.

Comment: I downvoted for lack of demonstrated search or other effort. (@JonSkeet probably thousands)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`yyyy-MM-dd` is effectively a **LocalDate**. What you're trying to do is convert it to **LocalDateTime**.

From [howtodoinjava.com](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/localdate-localdatetime-conversions/)

You could either set the time to `00:00` with

```java
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2019-01-04");

//Beginning of the day
LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = localDate.atStartOfDay();
System.out.println(localDateTime1);
```

Use the current time with

```java
//Current time
LocalDateTime localDateTime2 = localDate.atTime(LocalTime.now());
System.out.println(localDateTime2);
```

Or add the `12:00:0` with

```java
//Specific time
LocalDateTime localDateTime3 = localDate.atTime(12, 12, 0);
System.out.println(localDateTime3);
```

Note that you always need the first line of code

```java
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2019-01-04");
```

To format your `LocalDateTime` in a specific way, use `DateTimeFormatter`. For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String formattedDate = localDateTime1.format(dtf);
```

Comment: The old SimpleDateFormat should be replaced by [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) even if it works here. It is not thread-safe, and the new class has more features (negative year and such). For the rest a superb answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen The use of `SimpleDateFormat` did not work (it compiled but threw an exception when run). So I have substituted with the correct (and modern and thread-safe) code.

Comment: Detail, don’t use `000` as a number. It works, but you’ll be surprised when `070` gives you 56 seconds and `099` refuses to compile. A number with a leading zero (except 0 alone) is taken to be an [octal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). Just use `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using the following function:

```
LocalTime myTime = LocalTime.parse("12:00:12.000");    
LocalDateTime myDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(myInputDate, myTime);
```

and `myDateTime` will output: `2022-03-15T12:00:12`